# Is the surface bounding the complement of an unlink in 3-space incompressible?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $L$ be an unlink of $n>1$ components in $\mathbb{S}^3$. Let $N=\mathbb{S}^3-L$. Is the boundary of $N$ incompressible?

Comment: Can you find a non trivial curve on $\partial N$ that bounds a disk in $S^3 - L$?

Comment: Because each component of $L$ is the trivial curve, I don't think we can find such a non trivial curve in $\partial N$.

Comment: $\partial N$ is a union of disjoint tori, not curves.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly, the question is malformed.  A compressible surface must be compact and properly embedded in the ambient space.  If we take $N$ to be the ambient space, its boundary is not a properly embedded surface so is neither compressible nor incompressible.  To overcome this objection, we take the compact properly embedded surface, $S$, to be a collar of $\partial N$ -- a boundary parallel copy of the boundary, displaced into $N$ by an amount small enough that $S$ is embedded (not self-intersecting).

Note that when you delete an unknot from $S^3$, the resulting boundary component is a torus, $T^2 \simeq S^1 \times S^1$.  So now we ask if $\partial N$, a union of disjoint tori, is compressible.

Pick a torus boundary component, $t$, and pick  preferred longitude, $\ell$, of $t$.  (The preferred longitude does not link the "missing" solid torus, so is nullhomotopic in $N$.  The homotopy exhibiting this traces out a disk in $N$.)  This $\ell$ bounds a properly embedded disk in $N$, but does not bound a disk in $t$ (or $S$) so is a nontrivial compressing disk.  Since $S$ has a nontrivial compressing disk, it is compressible

An embedding of the properly embedded disk is in red with $t$ in orange.  (The grid lines on the torus are families of meridians and preferred longitudes.)

[image: Nontrivial compressing disk of a torus complement]

The red disk bounds an annulus, not a disk, in $S$.